# How can i append elements from two lists into an empty one, using FOR loops?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am iterating with a for loop around two lists, and i want to append the values to an empty list, but with the append method i cant because it only receives one argument.

```
list1 = ["Luis","Adolfo"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
  for y in list2:
     lista3.append(x,y)
```

I was expecting something like:
luis 1
luis 2
luis 3 etc...
adolfo 1
adolfo 2
adolfo 3

Comment: Can you show the expected output as formatted Python code?

Comment: I can't tell if you want to get strings or tuples back.

Comment: Append accepts only one argument at a time, so you need to decide very carefully what it is that you want to append.

Comment: Do you want `['Luis', 1, 'Luis', 2...]` or `['Luis 1', 'Luis 2'...]`?

Comment: Yes, i get an error with the append method, what i wanted to do is for each element in lista1 iterate through each element in lista2, so the output could be (luis1,luis2,luis3 etc) once it finishes with the first element in the list, proceed with the second element in lista1 an do the same procedure(adolfo1,adolfo2,adolfo3) and those outputs append them to the lista3, which is the empty list

Comment: Is it `['Luis', 1, 'Luis', 2...]` or `['Luis 1', 'Luis 2'...]`, what is the output you require @LuisRodriguez ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh - I think that's what he wants, which is shown in my third example in my answer.

Comment: Yes I see that, I just wanted to clarify it with the OP Thanks @Steve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list can contain just about anything.  So it's just a matter of what you want to add to the list for each x,y pair you have inside your loop.  you could create an inner list to hold both x and y:

```
from pprint import pprint
list1 = ["Luis","Adolfo"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
  for y in list2:
     xylist = [x,y]
     lista3.append(xylist)
pprint(lista3)
```

result:

```
[['Luis', 1],
 ['Luis', 2],
 ['Luis', 3],
 ['Luis', 4],
 ['Luis', 5],
 ['Luis', 6],
 ['Luis', 7],
 ['Luis', 8],
 ['Luis', 9],
 ['Adolfo', 1],
 ['Adolfo', 2],
 ['Adolfo', 3],
 ['Adolfo', 4],
 ['Adolfo', 5],
 ['Adolfo', 6],
 ['Adolfo', 7],
 ['Adolfo', 8],
 ['Adolfo', 9]]
```

or you could turn each x and y into a string:

```
list1 = ["Luis", "Adolfo"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        str = "{} {}".format(x, y)
        lista3.append(str)
for str in lista3:
    print(str)
```

result:

```
Luis 1
Luis 2
Luis 3
Luis 4
Luis 5
Luis 6
Luis 7
Luis 8
Luis 9
Adolfo 1
Adolfo 2
Adolfo 3
Adolfo 4
Adolfo 5
Adolfo 6
Adolfo 7
Adolfo 8
Adolfo 9
```

Or you could add x and y to the list individually:

```
list1 = ["Luis", "Adolfo"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        str = "{} {}".format(x, y)
        lista3.append(x)
        lista3.append(y)
print(lista3)
```

result:

```
['Luis', 1, 'Luis', 2, 'Luis', 3, 'Luis', 4, 'Luis', 5, 'Luis', 6, 'Luis', 7, 'Luis', 8, 'Luis', 9, 'Adolfo', 1, 'Adolfo', 2, 'Adolfo', 3, 'Adolfo', 4, 'Adolfo', 5, 'Adolfo', 6, 'Adolfo', 7, 'Adolfo', 8, 'Adolfo', 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
list1 = ["Luis","Adolfo"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
  for y in list2:
     temp = x+" "+str(y)

     lista3.append(temp)

  print(lista3)
```

Output:

```
['Luis 1', 'Luis 2', 'Luis 3', 'Luis 4', 'Luis 5', 'Luis 6', 'Luis 7', 'Luis 8', 'Luis 9', 'Adolfo 1', 'Adolfo 2', 'Adolfo 3', 'Adolfo
 4', 'Adolfo 5', 'Adolfo 6', 'Adolfo 7', 'Adolfo 8', 'Adolfo 9']
```

Comment: You'll probably want a space in there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can take all possible combinations of the elements of the two lists via [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
Then you can join the two items in each tuple of the lists with possible combinations to a string and make the resultant list

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ["Luis","Adolfo"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#Take all possible combinations using product, then join the two items in each tuple of the list to a string 
lista3 = ['{} {}'.format(item[0], item[1]) for item in product(list1, list2)]
print(lista3)
```

The output will be

```
['Luis 1', 'Luis 2', 'Luis 3', 'Luis 4', 'Luis 5', 'Luis 6', 
'Luis 7', 'Luis 8', 'Luis 9', 'Adolfo 1', 'Adolfo 2', 
'Adolfo 3', 'Adolfo 4', 'Adolfo 5', 'Adolfo 6', 'Adolfo 7',
 'Adolfo 8', 'Adolfo 9']
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use **itertools** and **list comprehension**

```
import itertools
list3 = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
list3 = [i + ' ' + str(j) for i, j in list3]
```

Result:

```
['Luis 1', 'Luis 2', 'Luis 3', 'Luis 4', 'Luis 5', 'Luis 6', 'Luis 7', 'Luis 8', 'Luis 9', 'Adolfo 1', 'Adolfo 2', 'Adolfo 3', 'Adolfo 4', 'Adolfo 5', 'Adolfo 6', 'Adolfo 7', 'Adolfo 8', 'Adolfo 9']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Python>=3.6`, you should probably try this.

```
list1 = ["Luis","Adolfo"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lista3 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        lista3.append(f'{x} {y}')
print(lista3)
```

**Output:**

```
['Luis 1', 'Luis 2', 'Luis 3', 'Luis 4', 'Luis 5', 'Luis 6', 'Luis 7', 'Luis 8', 'Luis 9', 'Adolfo 1', 'Adolfo 2', 'Adolfo 3', 'Adolfo 4', 'Adolfo 5', 'Adolfo 6', 'Adolfo 7', 'Adolfo 8', 'Adolfo 9']
```